# How to print file tree with hadoop?

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, command

I'm a new bird in HDFS and *nix, and I'm just curious, how to print a file tree in hadoop?

for example, we can type "tree" in any *nix system, and give us a result like that:

```
[admin~]$tree
.
├── backup_snapshot.sh
├── project
│   ├── doc
│   │   └── README
│   ├── src
....
```

that is very clearly output, but since the HDFS is not fully POSIX compliant, so I'm not sure how to print that in hadoop.

Comment: like linux command `tree`

Answer (score 25):

Based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(Unix) you can come up with a tree like representation, e.g:

```
hadoop fs -lsr /mydir | awk '{print $8}' | \
sed -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/-/|/'
```

Comment: This is indefensibly silly, but I wanted to do it in awk, so here we go: `hadoop fs -ls -R /mydir | awk '{print $8}' | awk -F/ '{printf " |-";for(i=3;i<NF;i++){printf "--"} print $NF}'`

Comment: Updated version (avoids deprecation warning): `hdfs dfs -ls -R /mydir | awk '{print $8}' | sed -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/ /' -e 's/-/|/'`

Answer (score 3):

Just created a simple project that does exactly this: http://github.com/trovit/hdfstree

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if you *really* want that (though I don't know why would you want to, except for debugging / visualization / entertainment purposes), you can [mount HDFS as normal filesystem using fuse](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS) - there are a couple of implementations available. That would give you a directory that you can run your favorite "tree" visualizer or whatever you are used to with normal filesystems.

Comment: We have hdfs mounted as a device on our machines. Tree command works extremely slow in case of large files/dirs inside a tree structure with mounted hdfs.

Comment: That's exactly why I said that it would be ok only for debugging / visualization purposes...